# Assigning a set properties to each element of a list python

Tags: python, list, class

I have a list containing unique items (names if you will) that changes every time I run my script. All of these items have some calculated properties that are modified during the script. For example 'S1' will have pos = 55 and ori = 'R'. I'd like an easy way to access these properties based on their name.

What is the best way to 'assign' these properties? I have been looking around and dictionaries do not seem be the right way to go forward so I tried with classes and made the following non-functional code code:

```
class Primer: #contains all properties of a primer
    def __init__(self):
        """ Contains all properties of the primer """
        self.pos = 0 #outermost 5' position in sequence to bind
        self.ori = '' #F(orward) or R(everse)


primer_list = ['S', 'M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'E']

for i in primer_list:
        i = primer()

print S.pos #this should give me the pos value of 'S'
```

Am I on the right track but missing something or is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mentioned that I also need to get my values back somehow. Equally clueless how to do this

```
print primer_list[0].pos #should give me the pos value of S in my example
```

Comment: Does all these items have the same properties? `pos` and `ori`? Does they need to be initialize with certain values?

Comment: @galah92 they all have the same amount of properties but the values change e.g. ori can be 'F' or 'R'. They should initialize with blank values but these should will be assigned during later steps in the script

Comment: Then I would go with class just as you made. I believe it will help you structure your code and make it more readable.

Comment: You said, "items (names if you will) that change every time i run my script". If the names change every time you run the script, how do you expect to access based on "name"?

Comment: So how do I assign the class to each element of my list? The loop I have written does not work

Comment: @BiRico I'd like to iterate over the list to get them back. I know it sounds convoluted which is why I doubt if class is the right way to do this

Comment: It would work if you wrote i = Primer() and changed the init method to take the arguments in primer_list and apply them to each instance of the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were having problems with the list, you didn't actually replace the old values with the created instance. I also added a name field so you could keep track of each instance.

```
class Primer: #contains all properties of a primer
    def __init__(self, name):
        """ Contains all properties of the primer """
        self.name = name
        self.pos = 0 #outermost 5' position in sequence to bind
        self.ori = '' #F(orward) or R(everse)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

primer_list = ['S', 'M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'E']
new_primer = [Primer(x) for x in primer_list]

for i in new_primer:
    print i
    print i.pos
    print i.ori
```